# Eclipse setting zero permissions during build

Tags: eclipse, build, permissions

I'm using Eclipse Luna on Windows 7.

When trying to build an Android project, Eclipse creates bin directory, but fails to create anything inside it ("Could not write file: ...\projects\MyProject\bin\classes\com"). When examining the bin directory from Cygwin, it says permissions are 0000, and when trying to open it in Windows, it says "You don't currently have permission to access this folder".

Apparently, something went wrong after I copied this project from its original location (under eclipseWorkspace) to a different directory on the same drive, where all my other projects reside. Before I copied it, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I copied the project again (luckily, I saved the original tree), and this time it worked. I am still puzzled as to what caused the problem.